# My .ts file is not compiling to a .js file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a very simple app. Here is the file structure:

```
-myapp
    -node_modules
    -src
        -app.ts
    -package-lock.json
    -package.json
    -tsconfig.json
```

my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

my package.json file (note, the typescript compiler is installed as a dev dependency, not globally):

```
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  }
}
```

my app.ts file:

```
let x:string
```

FYI- I'm using Sublime text as my text editor. And I'm doing the following in the bash shell on a MAC:

I'm trying to compile all of the `.ts` files in the `src` directory into `.js` files. However, in my bash shell when I cd to the root directory of `myapp` and run `tsc` I get: `-bash: tsc: command not found`

Comment: How are you running `tsc`? Plain `tsc` or `npx tsc`?

Comment: I'm only running `tsc`...nothing else

Comment: Then try `npx tsc` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

To run locally installed modules, you have to use npm scripts

Add this to `scripts` in `package.json`:

```
// any name you want
"compile": "tsc"
```

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  }
}
```

You can also use `npx tsc`, but it will **not** use the version installed